# Android App > Widget (AppWidgetProvider) > How to make a toggle button?

Tags: android, background, widget, alignment, togglebutton

I want to create a very simple widget. 1x1 cell. A button with text underneath. See image below, the 'clock' icon/text is how i want it aligned.. 'hello' is my effort so far.. It would be very nice to have a toggleButton, so with two states, after a click it should freeze the 'pressed' state. After another click it should return to the normale state.

My wishes:
- I want to create a Widget:
- 1x1 Cell
- A togglebutton (offcourse two states: normal & pressed, pressed must be freezed after click)
- Text underneath
- Toggle button has got a background, ratio must be 4:4 all the time. perfect circle.
- The text must also change to another string when the button is freezed in 'pressed' state

Since toggleButtons are not supported in widgets im looking for a quality answer. Im strugling with alignment of text, toggleButton in widget, background: keeping the ratio 4:4 instead of stretching... so what is the best approuch? how do other widgets build it?

See image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnAS3.jpg

my code so far:
http://paste2.org/p/2414784

Help would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

***edit:*** Similar SO question with code sample, kudos Mortalus:

[Making a Toggle Button in an AppWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862460/making-a-toggle-button-in-an-appwidget)

Tutorial for creating toggle-buttons in an `Activity`:

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/create-a-toggle-button/

And a great tutorial about creating `AppWidget`s:

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/05/24/developing-android-home-screenwidgets/

I take it you got 40dp from the widget guidelines, an excellent resource:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html

I noticed your image seems constrained horizontally, and stretched vertically, which seems to match these lines of your `Button`:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

You can try setting both to `wrap_content` (or, conversely, to `match_parent`) to even them out.
As far as alignment, a bit more info is available here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#AddingMargins

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Question: the links you sent for togglebuttons is a tutorial for togglebuttons in a application. I want to have a togglebutton in a widget. Since this is not supported i need some kind of work around. Any ideas?

Comment: Adding a link that has more completed code, kudos to Mortalus for preventing me from copying and pasting another example :D